# Accessing an OCX or activeX with PHP

Tags: php, activex, ocx

I know it is a not everyday issue. But we are trying to access an OCX with php code (not client). The php documentation has a COM object (http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php).

Does it work with OCX?

I know that the php server has to be a Windows server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to, I have done so in the past (long ago to be honest), works with some, create in the usual way:

```
$moo = new COM("thing.ocx");
```

Assuming it's registered and all that usual stuff :)